# Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Method get_site_editor_type does not exist

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Literally after doing nothing on the site, after several days of non-use, when trying to log in, such an error appears:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Method get_site_editor_type does not exist in /usr/home/midas/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php:45
```

theme-document.php:

```
protected static function get_site_editor_type_bc() {
    static $types = [];

    $class_name = static::get_class_full_name();

    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass( $class_name ); //45 line
    $method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );

    // It's own method, use it.
    if ( $class_name === $method->class ) {
        return static::get_site_editor_type();
    }

    // _deprecated_function( 'get_name', '3.0.0', 'get_site_editor_type' );

    // Fallback, get from class instance name (with caching).
    if ( isset( $types[ $class_name ] ) ) {
        return $types[ $class_name ];
    }

    $instance = new static();

    $types[ $class_name ] = $instance->get_name();

    return $types[ $class_name ];
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you manage to fix this ? I am struggling here. I tried rolling back the elementor version, plus commenting out the lines... I can view my pages in elementor theme editor as they are, but on my live site, it's showing 404 not found page :(

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Change the code

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass( $class_name ); //45 line
$method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );

// It's own method, use it.
if ( $class_name === $method->class ) {
    return static::get_site_editor_type();
}
```

By

```
if (method_exists($class_name, "get_site_editor_type")) {
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass( $class_name );
    $method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );
    
    // It's own method, use it.
    if ( $class_name === $method->class ) {
        return static::get_site_editor_type();
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone who's checking code line by line, OP has only added if condition.

Comment: much obliged sire. you cured my headache

Comment: Editing the plugin's code may result to the error reappearing after plugin upgrade. I'm just mentioning this isn't bestpractice though it worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Error tanked both backend and frontend of site. Thanks for sharing. I'd keep this modded file handy in dev in case future updates don't correct this. This could be really bad if you have auto-updates enabled in your plugins.

Comment: Worked for me on a old WordPress I had to edit.

Answer (score 33):

I solved this similarly to Mayous. I simply commented out the line in `/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php`.
So line 46 was

```
$method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );
```

Changed it to

```
//$method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );
```

Comment: Didn't work. There's a line right below it that uses $reflection so now that throws an error.

Comment: Works for me. I find it highly disturbing that Elementor keeps pushing faulty releases.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps there are two buggy versions, and this fixes one of the buggy versions.

Comment: I had to comment out the condition that followed as well (so 4 lines total) because it checked `$method`.  I could then log in.  The problem for me was caused by updating Elementor Free but not Elementor Pro.  Updating Elementor Pro to the latest made things right and wiped out the commented code.

Answer (score 10):

Go to: /wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php

Comment out line 47

```
$method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );
```

Wait for a fix to update.

Comment: Didn't work. There's a line right below it that uses $reflection so now that throws an error.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue today and have resolved it by rolling back the free version of Elementor, it's due to a bug in the recent update.

Comment: hey, what version number is the free version? did you try rolling back to any  paid version?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the site crashed for admins (logged in users), so was impossible to log in.

My solution was to shut down "Elementor pro" (using the admin console of my wp hosting), and then I could login and manually upload a new version of Elementor pro.

With no way to disable the plugin, I guess editing the code would also work, just comment out line 47 in:

/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php