# Fatal error after updating or installing Elementor or Elementor Pro?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I got this error while updating Elementor / Elementor Pro, and now the WordPress dashboard is not showing. Can anyone help me to resolve it? Thank you.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Method get_site_editor_type does not exist in /home/customer/www/medplustest.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php:47
Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/medplustest.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php(47): ReflectionClass->getMethod('get_site_editor...')
#1 /home/customer/www/medplustest.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php(128): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Documents\Theme_Document::get_site_editor_type_bc()
#2 /home/customer/www/medplustest.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/common/modules/finder/categories/create.php(94): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Documents\Theme_Document::get_create_url()
#3 /home/customer/www/medplustest.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/common/modules/finder/categories/create.php(67): Elementor\Core\Common\Modules\Finder\Categories\C in /home/customer/www/medplustest.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php on line 47
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276652/fatal-error-uncaught-reflectionexception-method-get-site-editor-type-does-not

Comment: The issue has been resolved, thank you. Marleen

Answer (score -1):

the problem is related to your elementor pro plugin. The specific issue is related to a missing method called "get_site_editor_type" in the file "theme-document.php" at line 47. you need to either re-install the plugin completely or redownload it and install it again. make sure you updated the elementor  plugin before updating the elementor pro .