# Elementor Pro E_ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

newbe here and with worldpress.

I am getting this error with Elementor Pro Version 3.3.6

---

This plugin failed to load properly and is paused during recovery mode.

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 48 of the file

`/data/user2/2021/182/33432/wordpress/.7898f453bbbcc2c64665ea922552af2a/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php. Error message: Uncaught ReflectionException: Method get_site_editor_type does not exist in /data/user2/2021/182/33432/wordpress/.7898f453bbbcc2c64665ea922552af2a/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /data/user2/2021/182/33432/wordpress/.7898f453bbbcc2c64665ea922552af2a/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php(48): ReflectionClass->getMethod() #1 /data/user2/2021/182/33432/wordpress/.7898f453bbbcc2c64665ea922552af2a/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php(129): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Documents\Theme_Document::get_site_editor_type_bc() #2 /data/user2/2021/182/33432/wordpress/.7898f453bbbcc2c64665ea922552af2a/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/common/modules/finder/categories/create.php(94): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Documents\Theme_Document::get_create_url() #3 /data/user2/2021/182/33432/wordpress/.7898f453bbbcc2c64665ea922552af2a/wp-content/plugins/elemento`

I am expecting the plugin to load correctly, I've already restared the plugin still not working.

Comment: As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276652/fatal-error-uncaught-reflectionexception-method-get-site-editor-type-does-not) I think this is a known issue with Elementor, You can try the approved solutions from that question to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you share the wordpress version and the php version? So may the versions are incompatible

Comment: @KargWare
PHP version 7.4.33 (Supports 64bit values)
WP 6.0.2

Comment: @VijayHardaha This fixed the issue and I am able to access the backend, however, the website lost the format.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by disabling the plugins by accessing via SFTP.